# Python: how to list subdirectories that match a list of folder names?

Tags: python, os.walk

I want to print a list of subdirectories that match a list of folders.

Here is what the list of folders looks like:

```
folder_list = ['AL_CLNC_2021',
               'AL_ICF_2021',
               'AL_IMD_2021',
               'AK_IP_2021',
               'AK_NF_2021',]
```

The directory tree looks like this:
NOTE: I don't want to include the "UPLOADED" folder to the path list that I output.

```
DirA--
     |
     -- Project
     |
     -- 2021 --
              |
              -- Alabama --
                       |
                       -- AL_CLNC_2021 --
                                     |
                                     -- UPLOADED 
                       -- AL_ICF_2021
                                    |
                                    -- UPLOADED
                       -- AL_IMD_2021
                                    |
                                    -- UPLOADED
              |
              -- Arkansas --
                       |
                       -- AK_IP_2021
                                   |
                                   -- UPLOADED
                       -- AK_NF_2021
                                   |
                                   -- UPLOADED
```

Here is the code that I'm currently using to create my list of directories:

```
path = 'path'

#we shall store all the file names in this list
filelist = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        #append the file name to the list
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file))

#print all the file names
for name in filelist:
    print(name)
```

I want the final output to look something like this, and only list the directories that are included in the folder from the initial folder list:

```
[/Project/2021/Alabama/AL_CLNC_2021,
 /Project/2021/Alabama/AL_ICF_2021,
 /Project/2021/Alabama/AL_IMD_2021,
 /Project/2021/Arkansas/AK_IP_2021,
 /Project/2021/Arkansas/AK_NF_2021,]
```

What is the best way to go about doing this to get the output above? Thank you

Comment: A dictionary might help - keys would be the folder names, and store the full path as value, once found... but your code is looping over files, not _just_ folders...?

Comment: @AdamSmooch: As written, their code never looks at the directories as they're found, nor checks `root`, so it's *only* checking files, not checking folders at all. That's a pretty trivial fix though (changing the loop over `files` to loop over `dirs` instead). You'd only want to loop over files if the matching things could be files, which the OP's case doesn't seem to require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the files, not the folders. And in your code, you use "file" for variable names which just confuses things. In each iteration of the `for` loop, `dirs` holds the list of subfolders found. You want the intersection of this list with the folders you are looking for, so just turn it into a set operation.

```
import os

wanted_folders = set(['AL_CLNC_2021',
               'AL_ICF_2021',
               'AL_IMD_2021',
               'AK_IP_2021',
               'AK_NF_2021',])

path = 'path'

#we shall store all the folder names in this list
folder_list = []

for root, dirs, _ in os.walk(path):
    for folder in wanted_folders.intersection(dirs):
        folder_list.append(os.path.join(root,folder))

#print all the file names
for name in folder_list:
    print(name)
```

Comment: Minor notes: 1. `set([...])` can be changed to just `{...}` to get the same result more directly/efficiently (so long as there is at least one element in the literal to distinguish from `dict` literals). 2. Using `intersection` to filter and produce only the matching folders, as a new `set`, does *slightly* change behavior, by replacing `os.walk`'s file system iteration order of the directories with the arbitrary ordering `set`s impose. Not necessarily bad (file system iteration order is pretty arbitrary), and won't matter unless >1 matched folders are in the same parent dir, but worth noting.

Answer (score 2):

Just tweak the loop to check if the entry found matches one of the desired names, and don't bother to check the files (because what you're looking for are directories):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for d in dirs:            # Loop over directories, not files
        if d in folder_list:  # Only keep ones that match
            filelist.append(os.path.join(root, d))
```

For large enough `folder_list`s, it may make sense to convert the `folder_list` from a `list` to `set`/`frozenset` so lookups are cheaper (either define it initially with `{}` delimiters instead of `[]`, or do `folder_list = frozenset(folder_list)` after it's populated, but before the loop begins), but right now, that overhead should be negligible next to the cost of file system access.

You can also arrest further nested traversal through matching directories (assuming you'll never find a matching directory inside another, and can save work by not looking deeper) by filtering `dirs` before the next loop begins, simply by adding:

```
dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in folder_list]
```

after (outside) the inner loop (so it runs just before you loop back to the next iteration of `os.walk`); `os.walk` looks for any in-place changes to `dirs` and uses the new version when descending further through the file system, so it won't try to traverse the excluded directories at all.